# Transit counted as Schengen days?

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

This is probably a duplicate, but scrolling is broken on the suggestions.

My multi-leg flight was DUB-BCN-LIS-JFK.  In BCN, they stamped an entry 30 03 2017 and in LIS exit 31 03 17.  I was only in the airport an hour or so and did not leave.

Should I protest this as an error, or just tolerate the extra two days cut out of my ninety?

To make matters worse, on this visit, entering BIO, the guy saw the BCN entry but not the LIS exit **on the same page** and gave me a hard time about it.  "How the hell are you coming in again when you never left?"  (Loose translation). Parked me on a bench while he went elsewhere, I presume to discuss it with the boss.

Comment: I can't give you any details on your question, but I've learnt myself to always double check the entry/exit stamp. And unless you had a transit flight for which you did not have to pass customs, you went into the country so it should count towards your days on the Shengen visa (I am not an expert on the Schengen visa so I'm not posting as answer). Other than that, I don't believe it's up to you to make sure the exit stamp is on the same page as the entry stamp, just make sure you've got it and maybe tell them where to find it if they're looking for it.

Comment: Did you enter the Schengen area in Barcelona on the 30th and did you leave the Schengen area from Lissabon on the 31st? From what you write, it is not really clear if anything is wrong at all.

Comment: Let me grab this occasion to ask, I always wanted to ask people who think that an intra Schengen flight is somehow transit: how do you think that would work? You board a plane together with people who never leave the Schengen area, what are you thinking happens? Somehow you are separated on the plane into a coral of people not-legally-entered-into Schengen or what? Really, what's the thought process?

Comment: @chx First, there are even people who think they can transit ...-LAX-JFK-... without a valid visa for the U.S., and second, since a Schengen flight is not a national flight, some people, especially from outside Schengen, may just not know that Schengen flights are basically national flights.

Comment: Are you saying that your three flights, DUB-BCN, BCN-LIS and LIS-JFK were all on the same day? *i.e.*, you were stamped in and out on the same day and one of the dates was wrong?

Comment: @Calchas: not sure.  It was definitely only a few hours, but it may have been over midnight.  There have been posts here suggesting that "transit" doesn't count.  If that's true, this is an error but probably not worth protesting.  I don't plan to use the whole ninety anyway.

Comment: @WGroleau Yep, there's no special exemption for plane passengers, you're inside the Schengen zone just like people who are on the ground. [The only exception is the odd fifth freedom flight operated by a non-Schengen carrier, for instance LA 704/705 between Madrid and Frankfurt is outside the zone, but that's because it is part of a longer flight between Frankfurt and Santiago.] If the date stamp was wrong you might be able to kick up a fuss but to be honest, it's not going to be worth it for one extra day.

Answer (score 8):

To make your BCN-LIS connection, you had to enter the Schengen Area, even if you stayed inside the airports. For this, you had to pass immigration - there was no way around that - and that's enough to make the two days count.

If you really need these days to not count against your 90 days in the future, you have to take a route that does not require you to board an Intra-Schengen flight (e.g. direct, via only a single Schengen airport, or via non-Schengen airports like London, Shannon, Moscow or Istanbul, to just name a few).

Comment: "you stayed inside the airports" + "the time on the plane for the connection (on airports and in the air)"